# .NET Core Web API project and Entity Framework 6 null exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am fairly new to both EF and .NET Core, but using a working project I was able to build a Core 2.0 Web API solution. The only issue is I am unable to get Entity Framework to instantiate on startup. I am receiving an error stating:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString

My Startup.cs file:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbc")));
        services.AddMvc();
    } 

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

My validated JSON file:

```
  {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "dbc": "Server=cc;Initial Catalog=dd;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
My Program.Cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: How is the configuration variable (that I'm assuming you are injecting into the Startup function) being created?  Is your Configuration property being set?

Comment: public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } in the startup.cs file

Comment: just posted an answer, I not sure how your Configuration knows about your appSettings.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Startup function to

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

to instantiate your configuration and use the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Same error which is being thrown in ConfigureServices()

Comment: This isn't the right answer. The default config when you use the 2.0 templates.

Answer (score 0):

The ConnectionString must be stored in the file name appsettings.json. Please try to move the Connection string part to the appsettings.json file and try.
For e.g.:
appsettings.json File

```
"Data": {
  "dbc": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=cc;Initial Catalog=dd;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
}
```

Startup.cs File

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:dbc:ConnectionString"]));
```

Comment: My JSON is in the appsettings.json file. As a test I used your format and still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, moving ConnectionStrings to the top of the apsettings.json file did the trick. Thank you all for your help.

```
 {
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "dbc": "Server=cc;Initial Catalog=dd;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "Debug": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "Console": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: did that work with your original startup code?  Also, your json looks off for the Logging section which I think is why it works to move the ConnectionStrings section up.

Comment: The logging section was definitely off which was the root cause. Oddly enough both variations validated using JSONlint. I fixed the syntax and now I can move the connectionstrings section around.

Comment: Yep, I guess structurally it was valid JSON, it just didn't make sense.  Glad it's working for you now.